# What is used for default string value in mapping?

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, mapping, string

For example, I have a contract like this:

```
contract example {
    mapping (uint => string) map;

    function example () {
        map[123] = "123";
    }

    function return1 () returns (string) {
        return map[123];
    }

    function return2 () returns (string) {
        return map[1];
    } 
}
```

When I'll call `return1`, it obviously returns `'123'`, but what happens on `return2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using your code as-is, when calling the `return1()` and `return2()`, you will have to send a transaction and you will be returned the transaction hash. If you are calling your `return1()` from another contract, your return value will be `"123"`. If calling `return2()` from another contract, your return value will be an empty string `""`. See the following screen:

[image]

If I add the keyword `constant` to the `return1()` and `return2()` declaration, `return2()` will return the empty string `""`. See the following screen:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You should get an empty string, as if you'd done

```
function return2 () returns (string) {
   string my_string;
   return my_string;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

in return2 you will get an **empty string**, in hex (0X000....000).